# Trouble to display a figure in the main panel of shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I try to display a histogram in the main panel of my shiny dashboard. The histogram is meant to appear in `dashboardBody> "Analyse de la concurrence" > "Part de marchés"`. The histogram is computed `in dashboardBody > in the second tabItem > in the second fluidRow > in the first box` by `output$hist`

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Analyses de la concurrence inter-hospitalière en IDF"),
  dashboardSidebar(width = 300,
                   sidebarMenu(
                     menuItem("Analyse des profils d'activité des hôpitaux",
                              menuSubItem("Tableaux/Barplot",tabName = "tab"),
                              menuSubItem("Cartes",tabName = "carte")),
                     menuItem("Analyse de la concurrence",
                              menuSubItem("Zone de recrutement",tabName = "Zrecrut"),
                              menuSubItem("Part de marchés",tabName ="Market"),
                              menuSubItem("Flux des patients",tabName ="Flow"),
                              menuSubItem("Indice de Herfindahl-Hirschmann",tabName ="hhi")),
                     menuItem("Analyse de trajectoires")
                   )),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "Zrecrut",
              fluidRow(
                box(selectInput(inputId = "Hopital1",choices = c(LETTERS),label = "Choisir l'hôpital 01" )),
                
                box(selectInput(inputId = "Hopital2",choices = c(LETTERS),label = "Choisir l'hôpital 02" ))
              ),
              fluidRow(box(plotOutput("histogram")),box(plotOutput("histogram")))
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "Market",
              fluidRow(
                box(selectInput(inputId = "Hopital1",choices = c(LETTERS),label = "Choisir l'hôpital 1" )),
                
                box(selectInput(inputId = "Hopital2",choices = c(LETTERS),label = "Choisir l'hôpital 2" ))
              ),
              fluidRow(
                box(title = "HISTOGRAMME D'UNE DISTRIBUTION NORMALE",
                    collapsible = TRUE,
                    plotOutput("hist")
                ),
                box(leafletOutput("MktShareCHIV"))
              )
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "Flow",
              fluidRow(
                box(selectInput(inputId = "Hopital3",choices = c(LETTERS),label = "Choisir l'hôpital 3" )),
                
                box(selectInput(inputId = "Hopital4",choices = c(LETTERS),label = "Choisir l'hôpital 4" ))
              ),
              fluidRow(box(plotOutput("histogram")),box(plotOutput("histogram")))
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "hhi",
              fluidRow(
                box(selectInput(inputId = "Hopital3",choices = c(LETTERS),label = "Choisir l'hôpital 5" )),
                
                box(selectInput(inputId = "Hopital4",choices = c(LETTERS),label = "Choisir l'hôpital 6" ))
              ),
              fluidRow(box(plotOutput("histogram")),box(plotOutput("histogram")))
      )
      
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$hist({
    hist(rnorm(100,100,5))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You have `box(selectInput(inputId = "Hopital1",...)` and the same ID is repeating again.  Each `inputId` should be unique.  Also, outputID should be unique.

Comment: Wow. You saved me